# How to update two tables at the same time with mysql?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I have a route where a user can make a post, I want to create the post in one table and update a field in another table.  I know that this can be done with back to back inserts, I am just not a hundred percent sure on how to do it. When a user makes a post, I want to create the post as well as update the boolean field hasPosts to true when they submit the post.  Here is my route.

```
router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {
   let token = req.headers['jwt'];
   if (token) {
      authService.verifyUser(token).then(user => {
         if (user) {
            models.listings.findOrCreate({
               where: { description: req.body.description },
               defaults: {
                  quantity: req.body.quantity,
                  availability: req.body.availability,
                  requirements: req.body.requirements,
                  description: req.body.description,
                  org_id: user.id,
                  deleted: false, 
               }
            }).spread(function(created, error) {
               if(created) {
                  console.log(created) 
                     res.status(200).json(created);
                } else {
                   res.status(400).json(error)
                }
            })
         } else {
            res.status(500).json(error)
         }
      });
   }
});
```

How would I go about piggy backing the request to update the users table field hasPosts to true?

Comment: looks like you are looking for "transactions": https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/transactions/

Comment: I am very new to this obviously, but I don't think transactions is what I am looking for. I will look into it though, thanks.

Comment: A transaction will let you do multiple updates one after the other, but only if they all succeed. If one fails, it will result in no changes made to the database. If all succeed, the promise returns when all operations have succeeded.

Comment: It's worth noting that you could use `Promise.all` with `models.listings.findOrCreate` and `user.set('hasPosts', true).save()`, but you could end up in a situation where either the listing fails to create and the user updates, or the listing creates but the user update fails, so data will be out of sync. This is what transactions are for.

Comment: You can define an [`afterCreate` hook](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/api/hooks/#aftercreatename-fn) in the `listings` model as well, which could update the user after a listing is created. It will be two separate queries still.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will look up how to define an afterCreate hook.